# Installing edimax 7811 uac

Tags: wireless

I installed the following driver for an external wireless usb adapter from this page:

https://github.com/diederikdehaas/rtl8812AU

But the adapter is still unrecognized. How do I get it to be recognized?

The driver is rt2800usb

```
lsusb
Bus 002 Device 010: ID 7392:a812 Edimax Technology Co., Ltd

uname -r
4.13.0-37-generic
```

Comment: Please clarify. rt2800usb is for a Ralink USB device. rtl8812au is for a Realtek USB device. Which do you have? Please edit your question to add the result of: `lsusb` and also: `uname -r`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I compiled the version you built and it doesn't cover your exact device, 7392:a812. I suggest you remove it:

```
cd rtl8812AU
sudo make uninstall
```

Next, to avoid any confusion in the future, remove it entirely:

```
cd ..
rm -rf rtl8812AU
```

Now, let's build a correct driver:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install git
git clone https://github.com/gnab/rtl8812au.git
sudo dkms add ./rtl8812au 
sudo dkms build -m rtl8812au -v 4.2.2
sudo dkms install -m rtl8812au -v 4.2.2
```

Reboot and tell us if your wireless is working.

You may be required to turn off Secure Boot in the UEFI or BIOS.

Comment: for background, I did this on Debian 10.6 and the Build step complained with `Error! Could not find module source directory. <br>
Directory: /usr/src/rtl8812au-4.2.2 does not exist`  so I had to symlink in where I'd cloned the repo to with      `ln -s /root/rtl8812au/ /usr/src/rtl8812au-4.2.2`